# text recognition (OCR) is switched off in Sikuli when using java

Tags: java, ocr, sikuli

Has anyone got the OCR function Region.text() working in Sikuli with java?

I keep getting this as output

> Region.text: text recognition is currently switched off

and I can't find anyway to turn this feature on in java.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1188599

Comment: Thanks, i had tried that before but i wasn't importing the Settings object. Got it now though im having another difficulty now as it wants a tessdata folder that isn't being created by the installer, though i have told it to do so.

Answer (score 10):

Sikuli has Settings class (org.sikuli.basics.Settings) that has options:

Settings.OcrTextSearch

Settings.OcrTextRead

Put them true and it should work :)

P.S. Actually I don"t know why are they by default false...

Comment: Thank you for giving the full path org.sikuli.basics.Settings

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Sikulix IDE app for 1.1.x, go to *Preferences*, *more options...*, you should enable allow OCR.

[image: Sikulix IDE app for 1.1.x, Preferences, options, allow OCR]

Comment: also make sure to have checked Pack 3 while installing - otherwise even this won't work